# Redis pubsub vs blocking operations

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

How should I choose between pubsub and blocking operations of redis ?

Redis gives blocking operations like `BLPOP` which blocks the operation till an element can be popped from the list. Why should I not use this to achieve the functionality of `PUBSUB`. `PUBSUB` allows you to define channels which are a higher level construct than the basic lists. If my usecase is simple without multiple channels, can I go with the basic blocking operations.

Answer (score 21):

There is an important difference between using lists with blocking operations and the pub/sub facilities.

A list with blocking operations can easily be used as a queue, while pub/sub channels do not involve any queuing. The only buffers involved in pub/sub are related to communication (i.e. socket management). It means when a message is published, it will be transmitted ASAP to the subscribers, it is never kept in Redis. A consequence is if the subscribers do not listen anymore to the Redis socket, the items are lost for these subscribers.

Another important difference is the pub/sub mechanism can multicast items. When the items are published they are sent to all the subscribers. On the contrary, considering multiple daemons dequeuing a list in Redis using blocking operations, pushing an item to the list will result in the item to be dequeued by one and only one daemon.

Blocking lists (i.e. queues) and pub/sub channels are really complementary facilities.

If you do not need to multicast items, you should rather use list with blocking operations, since they are much more reliable.

Comment: We can also add that with Pub/Sub feature **timestamp** of event can be generated by the subscriber (if one) in the receiving phase;    in blocking list case, the **timestamp** shuould be inside the **payload**, That's why we cuold have some cases where the list cannot be worked in real time and timestamp could be lost